# SIP stack for silverlight OOB application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, sip, pjsip

I wanted to know the possible solution of integrating a SIP stack with a silverlight OOB application. Is there any way to show caller id information in any current silverlight app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My C# SIP stack can run natively in Silverlight although be aware you will have to use SIP over TCP since Silverlight doesn't support UDP. You can find it at http://sipsorcery.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/73596 look at the sipsorcery-silverlight solution.